# php form inputs empty or null data a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a assignment which is a book "wishlist" that accepts a isbn, a book title, the author's name and a "book category". The website uses simple mySQL database that contains the values(The db has a "user_id number which auto-increments when data in entered in). It also uses some javascript validation embedded in the "create" page which is a small php page in theory serves to add book data, then prints the data the user entered in. My problem is that when I just run the page that processes the data, it enters in blank/null data. However, when I try to create a entry using the form page, it "craps out at the sql commands that post the data to the database. It connects to the database, but it seems to enter blank data instead the data I've entered. I'm sure it's some issue with the sql syntax, but I'm at wit's end.

db-connect (Makes the connection to the mySQL database:

```
<?php
DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'books');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

//if the connection wasn't success, then put out a connect error
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());
} else
    echo 'Connected successfully. ';
```

process.php (uses the db-connect.php file via the "require" command, then uses a sql "INSERT INTO command to insert the inputted data into the mySQL database, then prints the confirmation results if successful)

```
<?php
require("db-connect.php");

//$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
//$title = $_POST['title'];
//$author = $_POST['author'];
//$description = $_POST['description'];
//$categories = $_POST['categories'];

//echo $isbn, $title, $author, $description, $categories;


$sql = "INSERT INTO `books`.`books` (`isbn`, `title`, `author`, `description`, `categories`) VALUES ('"
    . $_POST['isbn']
    ."','"
    . $_POST['title']
    ."','"
    . $_POST['author']
    . "','"
    . $_POST['description']
    . "','"
    . $_POST['categories']
    . "')";

if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE ) {
    echo "The book was added to the wishlist.";

    //Print values by building a confirmation page
    $form_output = "<h1>Confirmed!</h1>"
        . "<h2>ISBN: " . $_POST['isbn'] . "</h2>"
        . "<h2>Title:" . $_POST['title'] . "</h2>"
        . "<h2>Author:" . $_POST['author'] . "</h2>"
        . "<h2>Description:" . $_POST['description'] . "</h2>"
        . "<h2>Category:" . $_POST['categories'] . "</h2>";

    echo $form_output;

} else {
    echo "There was a problem adding the book to the wishlist.";
}

//Close the db connection when finished
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

the form itself:

```
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block">
    <form name="myForm"
          onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" action="process.php">
        <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">ISBN:</td>
                <td><input title="text" name="isbn" id="isbn"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Title:</td>
                <td><input title="text" name="title" id="title"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Author:</td>
                <td><input title="text" name="author" id="author"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"> Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea cols="10" rows="5" name="description" id="description"/></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Category:</td>
                <td>
                    <label for="categories"></label> <select name="category" id="categories">
                        <option value="-1" selected>[choose yours]</option>
                        <option value="1">Science/Tech</option>
                        <option value="2">Children</option>
                        <option value="3">Art/Photography</option>
                        <option value="4">Politics</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is a screen shot of the phpMyAdmin screen. While it shows that something was entered, it's all blank save for the user_id field that increments

[image]

Comment: You've too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: Unclosed? Can you clarify?

Comment: when solutions are provided, the answer can be accepted by accepting it, with the checkmark underneath it. It's also a "win win" for all.

Comment: I still don't understand. Is this about my issue or did I not follow some rule of this website?

Comment: @JavaNewbie what he means is, that you ought to mark an answer as "that is the answer" if it solves your question. Otherwise all you question stay open and the people helping you do not get any points. You currently have 12 questions, none have been completed.

Comment: to your question: what kind of error are you getting from mysql when it "crabs out"? (you can get that from `mysqli::$error`)

Comment: Well, if you printed out what the actuall error was rather than just a generic error report, then you would have a chance figuring out what has gone wrong. Btw, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: Lord only knows what this JS method does `validate()`.

Comment: That's just it Shadow: There aren't any error messages from the browser! The data would be posted on the webpage, it just doesn't transfer to the database, It would show the following from Google Chrome (Navigated to http://localhost:63342/MyWishList/process.php). but the database itself doesn't display the data when I go into phpMyAdmin. The user_id increments, but no other data.

Comment: Funk Forty Nine: The validation () method is embedded in the create.php page. All the script does is put out a dialog whenever a user doesn't enter in any data and hits the submit button.

Comment: Erik, theres no error. the php script connects to the database, It doesn't seem to like the sql/php statement

Comment: Apex Capstone: both the db's name and table name is "books" thus that's why the INSERT INTO command is "weird".

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment corresponding variable and try this query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO books ('isbn','title','author','description','categories') VALUES ($isbn,$title,$author,$description ,$categories)";
```

If this works then accept this as answer. so no other person go through this again